# What is the meaning of 127.0.0.1 in Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

There are 2 servers in the same physical machine. The first server is for Front-end use through port 80, and the second server is for API use through port 81.

There are cross domain issues when I request jQuery Ajax from the first server to the second server. So I changed the configuration from `url :192.168.x.x:8080` to `url : 127.0.0.1`

An error appears as

> "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Unfortunately, I misunderstand the meaning of `127.0.0.1` in ajax.

What does  ajax call when the configuration is `url : 127.0.0.1` ,

The Server? Or my Client?

Thank you

Comment: It calls localhost, the server(s). If you set two different ports for each server, it should be fine AFAIK. So not sure what is your issue but just looks like a server one. Maybe you should instead ask question regarding `There are cross domain issues`?! You should enable CORS, different port means different domain

Comment: Yea 127.0.0.1 is IPv4 loopback, aka localhost. If you're running like AdBlock or some sort of local firewall or some AV's will cause what you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you  for your kind reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

127.0.0.1 is the IP address of localhost / the same machine. In fact 127.0.0.2 is the same machine too. Most IPs beginning with 127 refer to self.